# Can a mobile wallet like Trust be hacked using DEX?

Tags: blockchain, metamask, decentralized-exchange

I never shared my private keys or 12 words phrase with anyone. I users wallet generated by trustwallet only.

I had 4000 plus BSW staked in biswap platform launchpool.

When I saw that staking for bnb is slso launched, I wanted to buy more so I transferred 11 bnb from my binance to trustwallet.

Then I connected my wallet to biswap to swap. I kept connected for around 10 minutes as BSW price was dipping and I waited it to dip more. But suddenly I got notification that 11 bnb got transferred from my wallet.

After that all my BSW got unstaked from the pool and got transferred. And finally all other coins.

Few coins that were left the attacker sent bsc tokens to my trustwallet from his binance wallet to cover the fee and emptied all my coins, eth everything I had.

https://bscscan.com/tx/0x8d26f07d50a10243f50aeaa05dbf9437f8d2bb3982001447956715cc38ed7aed

This is the first transaction where attack started. You can check my address how all BSW were unstaked.

Is it possible for attackers to hack a wallet without private keys and seed?

Comment: Yes, you most likely clicked or approved a fake/clone of the original contract, in this case biswap. This way you could have approved a transferFrom or some other function that gives access to your tokens and the malicious actor could now move your tokens

Comment: Just to clarify, technically it is not a hack, because users have mistakenly approve something they should not.

Comment: yes, its rather called phising

Comment: I am pretty sure that wasn't fake website. It was real one where I staked earlier.

Comment: Tokens can be approved but BNB's cannot.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for attackers to hack a wallet without private keys and seed?

No it is not possible.

Ways to hack a mobile wallet

- User signing a wrong transaction: Do not interact with any portals from non-reputable and/or anonymous teams

Ways to hack a desktop wallet

- Malware. trojan, etc. on a desktop computer